# prevent duplicate cURL request

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments, restful-url

I'm having problems with this cURL code. For some reason "sometimes" it calls a restful API url twice.

This code is only called by stripe webhook after a stripe payment is made. Payment is charged once, but this curl is executed twice.

Any idea why this happens or how to prevent a duplicate call by curl to the restful api url?

```
            $url = "RESTFUL_API_URL";

            // Init cURL session
            $curl = curl_init();

            // Create array of options for the cURL session
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept: application/json'),
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                //CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
            ));

            // Execute cURL session and store the response in $response
            $response = curl_exec($curl);

            // If the operation failed, store the error message in $error
            $error = curl_error($curl);

            // Close cURL session
            curl_close($curl);

            if ($error) {
                echo "cURL Error: " . $error;
            } else {
                $response = Json::decode($response, true);
            }
```

Comment: Duplicate events are possible so it could be that: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#duplicate-events. It could also be that the above code is running for multiple different event types, so I recommend only executing it when you receive 1 specific event type (ex: payment_intent.succeeded).

Comment: @codename_duchess you mean stripe could push to `payment_intent.succeeded` twice for the same payment?

Comment: It's possible but shouldn't happen often. That's why your event processing should be made idempotent (see link I shared).

Comment: You ask " how to prevent a duplicate call by curl to the restful api url?"  The key words being "duplicate call by curl".  Curl does not make duplicate calls on its own.   If curl makes a duplicate request, it's because your code is calling it twice. Or the receiving server is executing it twice.  A duplicate request is NOT originated by curl.